# Custom Tcpdf signs multiple digits on the same filepdf

Tags: javascript, php, tcpdf

I am working on a small digital signature project, I use TCPDF to create files and digitally sign files. I need to sign multiple signatures on the same file but TCPDF doesn't allow that.
Is there any other solution or relies on that to change it?